# Why I cannot check OpenGL version in this fake OpenGL context?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, opengl-es

I'm trying to check OpenGL version creating a fake OpenGL context, but always I'm getting version 0. I create a fake context with this code:

```
  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
  ZeroMemory( &pfd, sizeof( pfd ) );
  pfd.nSize = sizeof( pfd );
  pfd.nVersion = 1;
  pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |
                PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
  pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
  pfd.cColorBits = 24;
  pfd.cDepthBits = 16;
  pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
  WINDOWINFO info;
  HWND mHWND;
 info.cbSize = sizeof(WINDOWINFO);
  GetWindowInfo(mHWND,&info);
  HDC mDC; 
  mDC = GetDC(mHWND);
  int fmt = ChoosePixelFormat( mDC, &pfd );
  SetPixelFormat( mDC, fmt, &pfd );

  HGLRC mOGLCtx;
  mOGLCtx = wglCreateContext( mDC );

  wglMakeCurrent(mDC, mOGLCtx);
```

And try to check version with this:

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION)
```

Comment: _"I create a fake context"_ Create a real one.

Comment: @LightningRacisinOrbit what's the difference? How I can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can create minimal OpenGL context with that:

```
HWND wnd = CreateWindow(
        "STATIC",
        "GL",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
        0, 0, 16, 16,
        NULL, NULL,
        NULL, NULL );
    HDC dc = GetDC( wnd );

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), 1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL,
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA, 32,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        16, 0,
        0, PFD_MAIN_PLANE, 0, 0, 0, 0
    };

    int fmt = ChoosePixelFormat( dc, &pfd );
    SetPixelFormat( dc, fmt, &pfd );

    HGLRC rc = wglCreateContext( dc );
    wglMakeCurrent( dc, rc );
```

Check OpenGL version with the same manner:

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION)
```

To be more efficient, after all:

```
// Clean GL context
wglDeleteContext( rc );
ReleaseDC( wnd, dc );
DestroyWindow( wnd );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get (`GetActiveWindow`, `GetForegroundWindow`) or create (`CreateWindowEx`) window handle before getting its DC or try to `GetDC(0)`.